# Reverse Array in TypeScript is too fast

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, reverse

I have a little problem with TypeScript. I want to reverse an Array. But before I reverse my Array, I want to write in into a local Storage.

The problem is, that I call the method to store the data **before** I call the method to reverse my array. But the stored data are already reversed.

Here is an example code and [here is the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20TSRunner%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20defaultArray%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reversedArray%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fillArray()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.defaultArray%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.reversedArray%20%3D%20this.defaultArray%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.reversedArray)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.reversedArray.reverse()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20runner%20%3D%20new%20TSRunner()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Arunner.fillArray()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A):

```
class TSRunner {

    defaultArray = []
    reversedArray = [];


    fillArray() {
        this.defaultArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        this.reversedArray = this.defaultArray;
        console.log(this.reversedArray);
        this.reversedArray.reverse();
    }


}

let runner = new TSRunner();

runner.fillArray();
```

The output is already 5,4,3,2,1. But I want to get the 1,2,3,4,5 and after that, I want to reverse it. Maybe you could explain me this behaviour. I think it has something todo with the call by reference stuff. 
Thanks before ;)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Why the `console.log` dupe target? The problem is `this.reversedArray = this.defaultArray;` because it doesn't create a copy of the array.

Comment: @Andreas The array is logged and *then* reversed, but when the console is opened and the array is examined, it will be `54321` because `console.log` examines objects only on demand (it doesn't deep-save the state of the object as it was when it was logged). The linked console.log question describes why he's seeing `54321` (and why the reverse *seems* to be happening too fast)

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. Simple .slice() and it works... :D

Comment: @TorbenG Note that `defaultArray` and `reversedArray` point to the same object. Both will contain the reversed array after your code has run.